# Change color of a field in a table depending on how much time is left for the user to pay with Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, python-datetime

I am trying to change the color of a field in a table depending on how much time is left for the user to pay, if there are 7 days to pay it should change to yellow and if it is already the date of payment or already had to have paid it should change to red, the one that changes to red I got it, but I can't get it to change to yellow when there are 7 days to pay.

This is my model and the def

```
class payments (models.Model):
    client = models.OneToOneField(HealthQuests, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name= 'Cliente')
    date = models.DateField(default=datetime.date.today, verbose_name= 'Fecha de facturación')
    payment_date = models.DateField(default=datetime.date.today, verbose_name= 'Fecha de pago')
    amount = models.FloatField(verbose_name='Monto de pago', default=0)

    def payment_yellow (self):
        return date.today() - payments.payment_date

    def payment_red (self):
        return date.today()
```

And my html and the if

```
<tbody>
            {% for obj in object_list %}
                <tr>
                    <td><a href="update_payments/{{ obj.id }}" class="btn">{{ obj.client }}</a></td>
                    <td>{{ obj.date }}</td>
                    <td>
                    {% if obj.payment_date <= obj.payment_red %}
                        <div class="p-3 mb-2 bg-danger text-white">{{ obj.payment_date }}</div>
                    {% elif obj.payment_yellow >= 7 %}
                        <div class="p-3 mb-2 bg-warning text-white">{{ obj.payment_date }}</div>
                    {% else %}
                        {{ obj.payment_date }}
                    {% endif %}
                    </td>
                    <td>{{ obj.amount }}</td>
                </tr>
            {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
```

Comment: As a general comment, define something like this as a model method and keep the template simple. Model: `def payment_display_class(self): ... if ... return 'bg-danger' ...` and in the template `class=" ... {obj.payment_display_class}" `

Comment: @nigel222 Yes you're right, we should keep business logic in views and models not in the templates :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you hardcoded the condition check to `7` in the template, the function returns `timedelta` between current date and the payment date.

Also, it should be `self.payment_date` not `payments.payment_date`.

So currently you should extract days to make your code work in `payment_yellow()` method so:

```py
def payment_yellow(self):
    return (self.payment_date - date.today()).days
```

> **Note:** Django models are generally written in `PascalCase` and don't require `s` to be added as suffix, as it is by default added, so it is better to name it as `Payment` not <s>`payments`</s>.

Comment: I love you men, but already change beacause I put obj.payment_yellow == 7, and it changes when equal to 7, but not when there are 6, 5, 4, 3, 2 or 1 day left to pay, how can I make it not be == 7, if not a number between 7 and 1, I guess.

Comment: @AxelBonillaNavarro just a minor mistake it should be `obj.payment_yellow <= 7` not `obj.payment_yellow >= 7` kindly check it bye :)